# Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a component `ListComponent` that needs to be used in 2 modules, one of them is lazy loaded. So I created SharedModule that declares ListComponent. ListComponent uses the `routerLink` directive, so it needs RouterModule. So I imported RouterModule, which resulted in this error.

> core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use
>   RouterModule.forChild() instead.

A global search shows I am only calling `RouterModule.forRoot` once. My lazy-loaded module calls `RouterModule.forChild` and is the only other routing module.

I created a stackblitz with my exact same setup, but wasn't able to recreate the issue. It actually works. Still, I can't figure out what's different about my project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-component-b

Comment: The issue was I had somehow accidentally imported the root `AppModule` into my lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to import the `RouterModule` in `SharedModule` in order to use directives such as `routerLink` you can simply import it like this:

```
// ...
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule], //  <-- without the .forRoot call
})
export class SharedModule { }
// ...
```

Make sure in the base module of you app (usually `AppModule`, or maybe `AppRoutingModule` in your case) you import it with `RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutes)` so the link used in `ListComponent` work properly.

See more in [RouterModule API Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)

Comment: that's how I added it... I assumed it implicity calls forRoot?

Comment: No, it does not call `forRoot` implicity. You can use either alternative which fits your need. Usually, the `forRoot` alternative is used in the base module (or base routing module) and without the `forRoot` wherever you need to use directives such as `routerLink`. Moreover when there are child routesyou use it with the `forChild` method.

Comment: yes I am already using forRoot in the root AppRoutingModule and forChild in the lazy-loaded module.

Comment: @inorganik it should work this way. Did you try it? Any thoughts you'd like to share about this? I've used this myself as explained and it has worked.

Comment: did a global search for RouterModule.forRoot in my app and it is only called once. That's why I assumed simply importing RouterModule calls forRoot...

Comment: Turns out the issue was I accidentally imported the root AppModule in my lazy loaded module.

Comment: I find this very confusing. I'm getting the exact same problem RouterModule.forRoot() called twice since I'm importing AppRoutingModule in a SharedModule, and the SharedModule is also used in a Lazy loaded module. SharedModule has a breadcrumb component that uses the routerLink.

Importing just RouterModule makes all work again. But this goes against Angular documentation:

"RouterModule can be imported multiple times: once per lazily-loaded bundle. " https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#usage-notes

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was `AppModule` auto-imported by IDE in one of `page.modules.ts`

You can quickly check if that's an issue:

1. Search for `AppModule`
2. Find all import from all files except `AppModule` and `main.ts`
3. Remove them and corresponding import statements.